# select distinct window function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, rolling-computation

I have a data table like the following:

How do you select the distinct continuities for each Longitudinal distance in a 10-step rolling window?

Ideally, I'd want something in the Ideal output column in which the results are arrays.

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses arrays:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct c) from unnest(ar) c) as num_distinct
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(continuity) over (order by distance rows between 9 preceding and current row) ar
      from t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

Or, if you want the values, aggregate them:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(distinct c) from unnest(ar) c) as num_distinct
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(continuity) over (order by distance rows between 9 preceding and current row) ar
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: This code seems to return the number of distinct continuities?

Comment: @QuyVuXuan . . . I misread the question and thought that was what you wanted.  In any case, getting the list is just a minor tweak on the query.